# Datetimepicker layout error

Tags: javascript, html, datetimepicker

I init date:

```js
$('.for-data').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'ru',
  format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss'
});
```

And have this error

[image]

What the options I need set for resolve this problem? And I how debug layout for datetimepicker if I go to DOM panel and then datetimepicker close after click.

Comment: If you are using [eonasdan-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), did you include `bootstrap-datetimepicker.css` as shown in the [Installing](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#minimal-requirements) section?

Comment: * VincenzoC* yes

Comment: ok, anyway it is really a strange behaviour, but I'm happy you solved your issue with custom css style.

Answer (score 1):

I found soludion!

I run datetimepicker in `debug` mode and found in css bug:

```js
$('.for-data').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'ru',
  format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss',
  debug: true
});
```

Because I use `HH:mm:ss` block is weight so I add own css for fix this bug:

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

Hope it help you if you get error like me